# Specifying a minimum required C++ standard

Tags: cmake

According to the documentation, setting `CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED` to `ON` prohibits the build system from using older C++ standards then the one requested by `CXX_STANDARD`.

But this leads to "interesting" problems when combined with the WriteCompilerDetectionHeader module. e.g. when offering some form of "forward compatibility":

`set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)` and testing for `cxx_relaxed_constexpr`, then conditionally defining a macro that expands to `constexpr` leads to compilation errors on GCC 6.3.0 as the requirements of `CXX_STANDARD` and the usage of the macro are conflicting (the feature header using the actual feature set of the compiler, not the one offered by the compiler when requiring  C++11).

Is there any way to specifying a required minimum C++ standard, without prohibiting more recent standards (e.g. C++ 11 or later)? The only workaround I can currently think about would be to not set `CXX_STANDARD` and `CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED` at all and just "informally" require a minimum version of C++...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this easily. While you could extend CMake to continuously compile objects up-to (or down-to) a specific standard, this would take quite a lot of effort. There ways to possibly do what you want depending on your circumstances.

- Use non-conflicting macros. Using your example, use `#define MYCONSTEXPR ...` instead of `#define constexpr ...`
- Use larger conditional blocks based on the standard
- Is your project mostly one standard, but have a few files that need a different one? use CMake's `set_source_files_properties()` to set a new `CXX_STANDARD` or `COMPILE_FLAGS`.

Comment: Whilst I don't understand why the cannot easily done, I guess I'll simply add an option and have the user decide which standard should be used...

Comment: It's not easily done because generally, that's not how the compiler options for standards work. It's not a minimum value, nor a maximum value. It's an absolute value. When you give `-std=c++11` to `g++` for instance, you're telling the compiler to expect C++11 code only. Any constructs from C++14 or C++17 will be an error. Anything from previous versions of the standard that were dropped in C++11 will be an error.  Semantics can vary slightly between compilers, so thoroughly read the documentation for your compiler options.

Comment: Whilst that is true, this could/should be solved by the build system rather than the compiler itself. (After all CMake "magically" knows which language versions the compiler supports...) Note: CMake even supports falling back to older standards if CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED is OFF (which is even the default)...